# Explain the meaning of the two sentences

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, expressions, sentence

I'm a bit confused by these two sentences:

> The general government consumption expenditures are used as another
>   measure of government size, although they do not account for the full
>   government size. As a component of the expenditure method'for
>   estimating GDP, it is widely available. Data is taken from World
>   Development Indicators of the World Bank. The sample consists of 81
>   countries over the period 1961-2005. The panel is balanced and
>   consists of 3645 observations.

It would be great if someone could rewrite them in other words :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you explain more specifically what do you not understand? You may also be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I can't get the meaning of word panel here

Comment: @choster I've updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote appears to be taken from a 2009 paper entitled “[What is the optimum size of government?](http://ime.bg/uploads/335309_OptimalSizeOfGovernment.pdf)” by Dimitar Chobanov and Adriana Mladenova published by the Institute for Market Economics, Bulgaria.

*Panel* in this case is specialized language referring to the source of *[panel data](http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/stats_packages/stata/panel.htm)*, also known as *longitudinal data* or *cross-sectional time series data*, i.e. data which consists of observations of multiple phenomena taken over time. The authors are describing the data they use in their analysis; there are 3645 observations in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

*The general government consumption expenditure* is the statistic in question. Since there is one figure for each government, it is possible either to use the singular or the plural, though it is not correct to mix the two as the author does here.  The third fourth and fifth sentences explain how the statistic was derived, after the second sentence explains why the information is available from which to make deductions.